# Convert dataFrame to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I convert to numpy array as follows:

```
df.values
```

which gives the following output:

```
array([[2],
       [0],
       [1],
       ..., 
       [0],
       [1],
       [0]], dtype=int64)
```

However I want to obtain the list as follows:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you mean `df.values.tolist()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting column and then [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df
   a
0  2
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0

print df.values
[[2]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]]

print df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Or maybe:

```
print df.values.tolist()
[[2L], [0L], [1L], [0L], [1L], [0L]]

print df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()
[2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L]

print df.loc[:, 'a'].tolist()
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

print df['a'].tolist()
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

But maybe you need [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
print df.values.flatten()
[2 0 1 0 1 0]

print df.iloc[:, 0].values.flatten()
[2 0 1 0 1 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have a dataframe with one column and several rows.  Remember that this is a two dimensional array, you have to slice the first column then list the values within that column.

This should do it:

```
df[0].values.tolist()
```

`df[0]` - This selects all values in the first column.  For the second column you'd use `df[1]` third `df[2]` and so on.

You can tell the shape of your dataframe by running `df.shape`.  This will tell you how many rows and columns exist in your dataframe e.g. `(9,1)` which means 9 rows and 1 column